# Failed to add recipient: @localhost [SMTP: Invalid response code received from server (code: 555, response: 5.5.2 Syntax error. k4sm217886weq.33)]

Tags: php

I wrote PHP code that suppose to send mail via `smtp.gmail.com:587` (using `PEAR::Mail`) to users with their forgotten password upon request. I get this error message:

> Failed to add recipient: @localhost [SMTP: Invalid response code received from server (code: 555, response: 5.5.2 Syntax error. k4sm217886weq.33)]

I do not know how to handle this.

Answer (score 1):

Asking a remote MTA to send an email to 'localhost' makes no sense. Don't do it.